# Do we still need to keep this thread locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts, spam

I recently noticed [What was the first work to posit the equivalence of magic rituals and computer algorithms?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/what-was-the-first-work-to-posit-the-equivalence-of-magic-rituals-and-computer-a) being pushed to the front page. Currently, every answer is locked (maybe due to spam edits according to the comments). Is it still necessary to keep these posts locked?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so but best to wait for a moderator to check.

Comment: I wasn't a mod back then, but I checked the timeline for each answer. It was bad. [Really](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/17262/timeline), [really](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/16331/timeline), [really](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/16367/timeline) bad. You can also see in comments that one of the answers was unlocked at one point and then re-locked after more spammy suggested edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be fine now so I've unlocked them.  If you see any spam suggested edits (on those or any other posts) please ping a mod or raise a flag.

Answer (score 14):

The reason rejected spam edits used to be a problem is because even when rejected they were still publicly visible and spammers would use that as proof to their clients they had successfully spammed their site. That was changed over a year ago so that now you can only see edits rejected as spam / vandalism if you have an account and are logged in:

[Why are suggested edits that were rejected as spam or vandalism not visible to users who don't have an account on the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300945/why-are-suggested-edits-that-were-rejected-as-spam-or-vandalism-not-visible-to-u/300946)

Since that point I've seen almost no suggested edit spam on other sites so I'd say the answers could now be unlocked, but of course not being a regular contributor here that's up to moderators and I'm just giving some background on why it used to be a problem.